# Do I need three ps+ accounts if I have three PS4's in the same house?

Tags: ps4, destiny

I have 2 ps4's in my house and thinking of adding a third will I have to pay $150/year total for all systems to have ps+?

The reason I ask is that when I got the second PS4 for my kids for Christmas, I couldn't play destiny with my them even though they logged in with their names from their profiles on my ps4. It being Christmas, I just hurriedly plunked down the $50 so we could play. Now that I'm thinking of getting a third ps4 so we can all play destiny together, I'm a littl concerned with having to pay $150/year for all three of them so we can play together.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the accepted answer to [this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147835/playstation-plus-for-ps4-on-multiple-console-accounts)

I will highlight a couple key points I think apply to you, and hopefully it makes sense.

> The Playstation Plus subscription is tied to the SEN account, but that account can specify a single PS4 console as its primary PS4, which enables other (non-PS+) accounts to access everything on the console.
>
> So any account using that console (the one specified as the primary by at least 1 PS+ subsriber) can enjoy the benefits of PS+, when using that console. That includes multiplayer.

Meaning you can have non-PS+ accounts utilizing the PS+ subscription **if** playing on the same console, meaning you cannot also be playing (even I was not aware of this...).
Keep in mind this answer was from Dec 2013, so not all information may be 100% accurate currently, but I believe *most* should be.

However, I can tell you that multiple consoles cannot all play online using the same PS+ subscription, so I suppose the **TL;DR** answer is "You will have to buy separate subscriptions if you're all playing online on different consoles at the same time."

You're essentially wanting to use the same service 3 times simultaneously while paying the price for 1.