# Does having a Sub acct add charges?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

Okay, so I'm only 14 and I don't know what I'm doing, but I just made a sub account on my PS4.
Will it add charges to my moms card or will it just share the Plus member ship my mom has?

Answer (score 3):

No, having a sub account does not cost anything. If your PS4 is [activated as the primary console](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/settings/activation.html) for your mom's PSN account, [some of her PS Plus benefits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147835/playstation-plus-for-ps4-on-multiple-console-accounts?rq=1) (like playing online) will be shared with all her sub accounts and other accounts on the console at no extra charge.