# Can I have multiple PSN accounts?

Tags: ps4, psn

We got a PS4 and my question was if I could have multiple PSN account names, because my friend and I want to play with different names.

Comment: Thank you, can we also have other names than the other people? Because we dont want to have the same muliplayer name

Comment: Yes, it is impossible for two accounts to have the same name. If this answers your question completely, go ahead and mark the check mark to indicate that this question is answered in case anyone else has this question in the future! :)

Comment: Yes, in fact, they *have* to have different names. Sony will not allow you to create an account with a name that is already in use. Am I misunderstanding your question? If you're asking if one account can go by two names, the answer is no. That is a much-desired feature for people who want to change their PSN names (such as myself).

Comment: Thank you, now i know. I misunderstood your answer but now i get it. I think i closed the question now?

Comment: Can you please help me on how to close it? I am on a phone and i don't see any check marks.

Comment: No, you already did the right thing. You don't want to close the question.

Comment: Oh ok, well thank you again. I am going to go to sleep now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, yes, you can have multiple accounts. However, you will be a bit restricted on what content you can access across them.

For instance, if you purchase a game on account A and the PS4 is not account A's primary console, account B will be unable to access it. However, if account A *does* have this console listed as its primary, account B (and accounts C, D, E, F, and G) will be able to access content licensed to account A.

It's worth noting that only account A will be able to **download** games that it owns the license to. For instance, if you own the Season Pass for an episodic game like Life Is Strange, but don't have the episodes downloaded on the system, account B will be prompted to purchase the Season Pass rather than being able to simply download it. (This is from firsthand experience within the past week)

Another important thing to note is that all but the account with the PS4 listed as its primary will not have their PS+ benefits shared. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147835/playstation-plus-for-ps4-on-multiple-console-accounts?rq=1) for more info about that.